# How to print a list on another webpage after passing it with localStorage?

Tags: javascript, html, list, local-storage

This is my home.html code. I pressed a button in a different .html file. The names are added and stored in an array in the other file and passed thru localStorage and parsed in home.html. Then I looped thru the array to print the names. My issue is on the webpage on the server the names show but after I submit a name it replaces the previous name on the webpage. It's not making a list with one name followed by the other. Is there something I can add with javascript so the names don't keep updating or refreshing? Thanks!

```
home.html


<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title> Home Page </title>

            {% extends "navigation.html" %}
            {% block content %}

             <p> List of Names: </p>

            <ul id="List"></ul>


        </head>
            <body>
                <script>
                    var LL = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("newList1"));
                    document.getElementById("List").innerHTML += "<li>" + LL[LL.length-1] + "</li>";
                </script>
            </body>
            {% endblock %}
        </html>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title> Add Name Page </title>

    {% extends "navigation.html" %}
    {% block content %}

    <p> Add a name: </p>

    <form action="home.html">
    <input type='text' input name='name' id='addname'>
    <input type="button" id="add" value="Submit" onclick="passVal()">
    </form>

    <ul id="nameList"></ul>

add_name.html

</head>
    <body>

    <script>
    function passVal() {
    newList = [];
    var newName = document.getElementById("addname").value;
    newList.push(newName); //Note: push in javascript assigns value to newList. If I set this to a variable, it would only store the number of elements in that list
    localStorage.setItem("newList1", JSON.stringify(newList));
    }
    </script>

    </body>
    {% endblock %}
</html>
```

Comment: What's the code that adds the names to the local storage? Are you sure that all the names are in the localStorage, and that the script to add names doesn't override previous names?

Comment: I updated it for u adding in the other code. I had tested it with the code from home.html. in the same file and it printed out fine. I was wondering if it was because it refreshes from switching webpages so it only sees the most recent name? Is there a function I could write where it keeps the name from the last button push and keeps updating? Again, I'm new to javascript and html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for updating your post and including the add_name.html file. The main problem lies there. What you do in the passVal function is to start a new array, then add one value to the array, and then setting the list in the local storage to that array. Therefore the array in the local storage always only has one entry.

Rather than setting the newList variable to an empty array, you should set it to the list of items that are already in the local storage:

add_name.html

```
<script>
function passVal() {
    var previousValue = localStorage.getItem("newList1"); // Get the previous value
    var newList;
    if(previousValue) {
        newList = JSON.parse(previousValue);
    } else {
        newList = []; // If nothing is in the local storage until now, start with an empty list.
    }
    var newName = document.getElementById("addname").value;
    newList.push(newName);
    localStorage.setItem("newList1", JSON.stringify(newList));
}
</script>

</body>
{% endblock %}
```

Then in the home.html, you need to loop through the values:

```
var LL = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("newList1"));
for(let item of LL) {
    document.getElementById("List").innerHTML += "<li>" + item + "</li>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. It worked! I had that thought process too when passing it to local storage but wasn't sure how to go about fixing it. Graci Graci